# Which algorithm is best appropriate for finding Vertex Cover over large graphs using parallel approach?

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex-cover

There are lots of algorithm for finding vertex cover of a graph but want to know the best algorithm that can be used as parallel approach for finding vertex cover over large graph, so which is best? As i have asked this question bcoz the importance of this problem in real word application is more like in Terrorist Communication N/w, Airline Communication N/w, Wireless Communication etc.

Comment: Are you looking for optimal solution? Be aware that this problem is NP-Hard, and thus unless P=NP, every algorithm will have some cases where even with parallelism, it will be infeasible to solve these cases due to the long time required to solve it.

Comment: Not exact but nearer to optimal solution. Minimal not minumum. Minimal is NP Complete problem.